# Loop Causal Impact in R over multiple datasets and automatically export results

Tags: r, loops, statistics, time-series, causality

I need some suggestions on how to solve this problem. I have a number of zoo objects on which I want to perform a Causal Impact analysis in R, using the homonym package developed by Google. To automatize the process, I want to run a loop over the zoo objects and automatically save the results in a file to be exported in either word or csv.

So far, my solution has been to include the zoo objects into a zoo list by

```
    zoolist<-list(ts1, 
                ts2,
                ts3 
                 )
```

and then run a for loop like:

```
    for (i in zoolist)
{
  experiment_impact<-CausalImpact(i, 
                                  pre.period, 
                                  post.period, 
                                  model.args = list(nseasons = 7, season.duration = 1))
  summary(experiment_impact)
}
```

The code seems to work, however I don't have idea on how to export all the outputs in a csv or doc or whatever format, provided that it is compact and readable.

Any idea? Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code that creates ts1, ts2, and ts3 as well as an example of how you would like the output to be structured.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want to do is capture the summary, exactly as printed to the screen, you can use `capture.output`.  Replace the second line in your loop with:

```
capture.output(summary(experiment_impact), file = 'example.txt', append = T)
```

A more elegant solution might be to use `lapply` to run the analysis on each item in the list, so that you end up with a list of output items:

```
resultList = 
  lapply(
    zoolist, 
    CausalImpact, 
    pre.period, 
    post.period,
    model.args = list(nseasons = 7, season.duration = 1)
  )
```

You could then extract desired values from each of the CausalImpact objects in the list and format the values in a data.frame, which you could output using `write.csv`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It put me on the right way: since the Causal Impact object cannot be directly transformed in a dataframe, and your solution provides me with a large list object, I had to access the specific list inside my list of interest via export = lapply(resultList, "[[" , "summary") and then finally write the csv. Thank you!